# Add carriage return after node using for xml path

Tags: sql-server, xml, carriage-return, for-xml-path

How would I add a carriage return after every node for xml path creates? I've tried many different attempts and failed every time.

example query:

```
 select '', field1,
  (
   select field2 
   from blah2 for xml path('innernode'), type
  )          
from blah for xml path('node'), type
```

I have got a few results near what I am looking for, but nothing has hit the nail on the head yet.

example query:

```
 select '', field1,
  (
   char(13) + char(10) + convert(varchar(max),(select field2, field3, field4 
   from blah2 for xml path('innernode'), type)) + char(13) + char(10)
  )          
from blah for xml path('node'), type
```

The query above returns:

```
<node>
<innernode></innernode><innernode></innernode>
</node>
```

What I would like to see:

```
<node>
<innernode></innernode>
<innernode></innernode>
</node>
```

Honestly the below result would be acceptable as well.

```
<node><innernode></innernode>
<innernode></innernode></node>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I answered my own question by replacing the end node with end node + carriage return line feed on the inner selects output.